# Whoops- put turkey chili in the crockpot on warm all day. Is it safe once cooked?

Tags: slow-cooking, turkey, crockpot, pot, chili

I just called home & hubby said the chili was still raw when he got home . He turned it up to high and is making something else for tonights dinner. He did not  put in thermometer before turning it up. 
Is this safe to eat once cooked through? So mad at myself to toss it but don't want to risk getting us sick. Thanks for advice!

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Raw meat at near room temp all day is a high risk of food poisoning -- even if you kill any bacteria, there's still the toxins that would have been generated in that time.

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate question. I would check out the following:http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19232/used-warm-setting-by-accident
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/28809/put-pork-in-crock-pot-and-accidentally-set-to-warm/28817#28817
and more importantly:
http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Comment: Unless you can find out what "warm" exactly means, in degrees F/C and with a comparable amount of liquid, assume NOT safe.

Comment: In short, as you can't guarantee that the slowcooker brought the food to 140F quick enough and kept it above that, it's a dangerous gamble. 2 total cumulative hours between 40F and 140F is what is considered safe.

Comment: Turkey should be 165 degrees F.